# How to get SKU of custom options selected for item order programatically in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a product with multiple custom option customers can choose. For examples:

Product: Flower Basket of 10 flowers (SKU 100) 
Custom options:

- Red roses qty:   Drop down with 0 to 10 (each with SKU 200)
- Purple Roses qty:   Drop down with 0 to 10 (each with SKU 300)
- Pink Tulips qty:   Drop down with 0 to 10 (each with SKU 400)

This way customer can build their own basket. However, now I have to export my orders for warehouse system and I need to list Custom Option's SKU with value(qty). While I can get the label and value from Order Item. There is no SKU.

I am getting my items like so:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
              ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 'processing'));
foreach ($orders as $order) {

  foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $order_item) {

      $optionsArr = $order_item->getProductOptions();

       if (count($optionsArr['options']) > 0) {
            foreach ($optionsArr['options'] as $option) {
                $optionTitle = $option['label'];
                $optionId = $option['option_id'];
                $optionValue = $option['value'];
                // no SKU ?!?! 
            }
        }

  }

}
```

Any ideas how to get the SKU for every Custom Option selected?

Comment: You got the id so you can always load it from the catalog product options model l. This will provide you all the options attributes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try loading the product and getting an option collection.

```
foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
    $options = $product->getProductOptionsCollection();
    foreach($options as $option) {
        echo $option->getSku();
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case i am getting null on the option sku? Can you tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this way.

```
foreach($order->getAllItems() as $_item) {
$customOptions = $_item->getProductOptions();

        foreach ($customOptions['options'] as $_eachOption) {
            $objModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option_value')->load($_eachOption['option_value']);
            print_r($objModel->getData());
        }
}
```